# Detect if shift key is down React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

How can I detect if the shift key is currently pressed down? I have a text input, and when the user presses the enter key I only want to submit the form if they are **not** currently pressing the enter key (same form functionality as Facebook Messenger on desktop).

Here is my text input:

```
<TextInput
    style={styles.input}
    placeholder={'Enter message'}
    onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}
/>
```

And here is the handler:

```
handleMessageInputKeyPress(e) {
    if(e.nativeEvent.key == "Enter"){
        // Now check if the SHIFT key is currently pressed or not...
    }
}
```

Comment: `e.nativeEvent.shiftKey`?

Comment: @Teemu I get `undefined` when I add `console.log(e.nativeEvent.shiftKey);` inside the `if` statement.

Comment: ?? Then simply check `'Shift'` instead of `'Enter'`? Ah... Shift doesn't fire `keypress` ...

Comment: @Teemu But I want to check if the `Shift` key is pressed *at the same time* as the `Enter` key. How can I do that?

Comment: You need another event, like `keydown` or `keyup`, `keypress` is not fired by SHIFT, though `.shiftKey` still should be defined.

Comment: @Teemu So I could record that the SHIFT key is pressed on `keydown` and then record that it is unpressed on `keyup`. Then when the enter key is pressed, I would be able to check if the shift key is *also* pressed at the same time. I'll try that, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can use event listeners to detect any time a key is pressed (or unpressed), then filter the results for the key you want to use as a conditional. Here's an example using hooks:

```
  const [shiftHeld, setShiftHeld] = useState(false);


  function downHandler({key}) {
    if (key === 'Shift') {
      setShiftHeld(true);
    }
  }

  function upHandler({key}) {
    if (key === 'Shift') {
      setShiftHeld(false);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', downHandler);
    window.addEventListener('keyup', upHandler);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('keydown', downHandler);
      window.removeEventListener('keyup', upHandler);
    };
  }, []);
```

This will change the state to true or false depending on whether the shift key is held down or not. Then you can plug that value in anywhere you need it.
Tip: You can use this format to listen for any other key. I had a hard time finding documentation on what the keys are called. If you have trouble finding the key name, implement this code then console log `key` just before the `if` statement in the `downHandler`.

Also, make sure you leave the listeners in a `useEffect`, otherwise you'll get data leaks.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are still looking for the solution:

It seems the `event` received by the callback `onKeyPress` has the following properties:

[image]

It's nice to see it also has `ctrlKey` & `altKey`.

So the solution would be:

```jsx
<TextInput
    onKeyPress={event => {
        if (event.shiftKey && event.key === "Enter"){
            // ...
        }
    }} />
```

Comment: I'm not seeing this flags, not even the documentation mentions them, where did you get this info?

Comment: onKeyPress `event` doesn't receive above mentioned flags.

Comment: those flags are only available if you are using `react-native-web` and running on browser

Answer (score 0):

create a hook like this

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";

const useKeyPress = (keyMap, callbackMap) => {
    const [keyPressed, setKeyPressed] = useState(new Set());

    const downHandler = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      const { key, altKey, shiftKey, ctrlKey } = event;
  
      const modifiers = [];
      if (altKey) modifiers.push('alt');
      if (shiftKey) modifiers.push('shift');
      if (ctrlKey) modifiers.push('ctrl');
  
      // Generate all possible combinations of modifiers and key
      const combinations = [      [key.toLowerCase()],
        [modifiers.join('+'), key.toLowerCase()],
        [modifiers.reverse().join('+'), key.toLowerCase()]
      ];
  
      for (const combination of combinations) {
        const id = keyMap[combination.join('+')];
        const callback = callbackMap[id];
        if (callback) {
          const newKeyPressed = new Set(keyPressed);
          newKeyPressed.add(combination.join('+'));
          setKeyPressed(newKeyPressed);
          callback();
          break;
        }
      }
    };
  
    const upHandler = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      const { key, altKey, shiftKey, ctrlKey } = event;
  
      const modifiers = [];
      if (altKey) modifiers.push('alt');
      if (shiftKey) modifiers.push('shift');
      if (ctrlKey) modifiers.push('ctrl');
  
      // Generate all possible combinations of modifiers and key
      const combinations = [      [key.toLowerCase()],
        [modifiers.join('+'), key.toLowerCase()],
        [modifiers.reverse().join('+'), key.toLowerCase()]
      ];
  
      for (const combination of combinations) {
        const id = keyMap[combination.join('+')];
        const callback = callbackMap[id];
        if (callback) {
          const newKeyPressed = new Set(keyPressed);
          newKeyPressed.delete(combination.join('+'));
          setKeyPressed(newKeyPressed);
          break;
        }
      }
    };
    
      
  
    useEffect(() => {
      window.addEventListener('keydown', downHandler);
      window.addEventListener('keyup', upHandler);
  
      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('keydown', downHandler);
        window.removeEventListener('keyup', upHandler);
      };
    });
  
    return keyPressed;
  };

export default useKeyPress;
```

Then use can use it like this in your other components;

```
// Keyboard mappings
  const keyMap = {
    'ctrl+shift+p': 'preview',
  };
  const callbackMap = {
    'preview': () => setShowModal(prevModalVisible => !prevModalVisible),
  };
  useKeyPress(keyMap, callbackMap);
```

With technique you can map any three key combinations of your liking